# Tkinter, Canvas. Нарисовать спираль

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно нарисовать спираль?
Написал такую пародию на код

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()
step = 10
p = [145, 145, 155, 155]
iters = 0
canvas.create_arc(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], start=0, extent=180, style=ARC)

while p[0] > 10:
    if (iters % 2):
        canvas.create_arc(p[0] - step, p[1] - step, p[2], p[3],
                          start=0, extent=180, style=ARC)
        p[0], p[1] = p[0] - step, p[1] - step
    else:
        canvas.create_arc(p[0], p[1], p[2] + step, p[3] + step,
                          start=0, extent=-180, style=ARC)
        p[2], p[3] = p[2] + step, p[3] + step
    iters += 1
root.mainloop()
```

На выходе получаю такое:

[image: Спираль]

**Вопрос в том как избавиться от этой щели?**

Я пробовал играться с аргументами start и extent, но какого-либо *качественного* результата это не дало, потому что две части не совпадали друг с другом, т.е. что-то типо этого:

[image: Спираль2]

^ Тут я от балды ввел значения, попиксельно не подгоняя.

Сталкивался ли кто с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На каждом шаге нужно расширять эллипс (частью которого является отрисовываемая дуга) вверх и вниз одинаково. Если делать как у вас сейчас, то центры четных и нечетных эллипсов будут смещаться вверх и вниз от горизонтальной оси, из-за чего и получается зазор между верхней и нижней частью. Рабочий код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()
step = 10
p = [145, 145, 155, 155]
iters = 0
canvas.create_arc(*p, start=0, extent=180, style=ARC)

while p[0] > step:
    p[1] -= step/2  # расширение вниз
    p[3] += step/2  # расширение вверх

    if iters % 2:
        p[0] -= step  # расширение и сдвиг левой границы влево
        canvas.create_arc(*p, start=0, extent=180, style=ARC)
    else:
        p[2] += step  # расширение и сдвиг правой границы вправо
        canvas.create_arc(*p, start=0, extent=-180, style=ARC)

    iters += 1

root.mainloop()
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение!